# Connecting the HTML5 app to a database on a server *Safely*

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, rest, api-key

I am trying to connect a HTML5 mobile phonegap app to a database (MongoDB) safely. The app is going to be on the app stores and no one can see the code. I had a few questions regarding the same. As far as I know there are 2 ways to do this, one is using the RESTful services and the other is using database drivers (I am having problems with this method so used the HTTP request method). So here are my questions,

When I use RESTful services to connect to the database I have to include the HTTP query **which includes the API key**. My question: is it safe to use it this way? I am planning to store some sensitive information on the database but am planning to encrypt it. But I do not want anyone to see my API KEY because if one sees the API key then its easy to get access of the information on the database.
The API KEY is hardcoded in one of the javascript files.

Is there a safe way to use the REST API key in javascript?

Comment: Like JavaScript web applications, native mobile applications cannot keep secrets.

Comment: Best approach is individual access tokens for each user or device. That way, you can limit what data is accessible to this user, there is no need to hide the token from the user and it is also in the user's best interest to not leak his token to others.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy So not safe to hardcode the API_KEY in the code?
If so, what is the use of having a HTTP request when the data is not going to be safe? Am I missing some powerful and crucial feature of an HTTP request?

Comment: @Thilo - thanks for your help. I will look into this technique. Do you have or know any links which explain this technique in detail? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to have a server-side language such as PHP controlling the database in order to have complete control over how your database is used. You also must make sure the code isn't vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: Well, for all you might do, don't use PHP. It is a language you can get easy results with, but it is a horrible language to learn how to do things right, and if you aren't very careful, a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help. I learnt that **Hard Coding the API KEY** in the javascript code is a really bad idea as its not hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way is to put an [oAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) layer between app ([Client](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.1)) and DB ([Resource Server](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.1)). Here the "Resource Owner"  is the end-user.

You may use "Implicit", "Resource Owner Password Credentials" or "Client Credentials". Do read about "[Access Tokens](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.4)" and "[Refresh Tokens](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5)" also.

**Abstract Protocol Flow** (Copied from [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.2))

```
 +--------+                               +---------------+
 |        |--(A)- Authorization Request ->|   Resource    |
 |        |                               |     Owner     |
 |        |<-(B)-- Authorization Grant ---|               |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |--(C)-- Authorization Grant -->| Authorization |
 | Client |                               |     Server    |
 |        |<-(D)----- Access Token -------|               |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |
 |        |                               +---------------+
 |        |--(E)----- Access Token ------>|    Resource   |
 |        |                               |     Server    |
 |        |<-(F)--- Protected Resource ---|               |
 +--------+                               +---------------+
```

Comment: Okay so my understanding of this connection:
The Client layer communicates with a layer of oAuth 2.0 (this middle layer checks if the client layer has a valid request?) and then provides an individual access token for the database and can only see the things in their account on the resource server?

Comment: Somewhat correct. Let me clarify that the Access Token is given to the client not individual. I have updated the answer with a diagram from [here](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.2)